# EF Core Migrations with OwnsMany for abstract class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have some experience in using EF Core Migrations, and have also used `.OwnsMany()` with success.
In this case I cannot get a working migration for my model.

What I have is this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<OwnedBaseClass> SomeList { get; set; }
}

public abstract class OwnedBaseClass
{
    public string BaseProperty { get; set; }
}

public class AA : OwnedBaseClass
{
    public string AAProperty { get; set; }
}

public class BB : OwnedBaseClass
{
    public string BBProperty { get; set; }
}
```

If in my DbContext I do this:

```
public virtual DbSet<AA> AARecords { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<BB> BBRecords { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<OwnedBaseClass>().HasNoKey();
}
```

I then get a migration for a Table "OwnedBaseClass" with additional column "Discriminator" where it can distinguish between records of type AA and BB.

So far so good.

What I need is to have a migration for Class1 using `.OwnsMany()` for type OwnedBaseClass in OnModelCreating like so:

```
public virtual DbSet<Class1> Class1Records { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>(x =>
    {
        x.HasKey(a => a.Id);
        x.OwnsMany(a => a.SomeList);
    });
}
```

When adding migration I get the following error:

```
The corresponding CLR type for entity type 'OwnedBaseClass' cannot be instantiated, and there is no derived entity type in the model that corresponds to a concrete CLR type.
```

I can't seem to get around this.
If I add a DbSet for type AA (which seems wrong) I get an error:

```
The entity type 'AA' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating
```

If I then add (even worse)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AA>().HasNoKey();
```

I get another error:

```
'AA' cannot be configured as keyless because it is a derived type; the root type 'OwnedBaseClass' must be configured as keyless instead.
```

So this is where I am stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This appears to be an error in your understanding of relational databases. 
A derived type requires a relationship (primary key to foreign key) set between the two tables. Declaring you don't need a key, is saying the derived type is a derived type, without specifying which parent is the base class for it. 

It also seems that the "OwnedBaseClass" doesn't exist in your migration, meaning the system is trying to implement the derived type BEFORE the base table exists. 

That will obviously not work, for the same reason as above.

Comment: @MortenBork - I'm not sure I understand what you mean. From my first example I know that I can have a single table for OwnedBaseClass with a discriminator column to distinguish between derrived types, when I declare DbSet for AA and BB. What I need is to have this table created as owned by Class1.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant but ran into the same issue. This is a [known shortcoming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#current-shortcomings) on owned types:

> **Current shortcomings**
>
> Owned entity types cannot have inheritance hierarchies

I ended up configuring them as plain related objects with a `HasMany`.